# SELinux - add access rights for a new type

Tags: linux, selinux

I am new to SELinux and I need to create a new type for a file and then specify access rights for a standard Linux user with its security context: user_u : user_r : user_t. I created new module (.te file):

```
policy_module(FIR_policy, 1.0.0)

require {
  type user_t;
}

type FIR_t;
files_type(FIR_t)
allow user_t FIR_t:file { getattr execute read open};
```

I compiled and installed the module:

```
make -f /usr/share/selinux/devel/Makefile FIR_policy.pp
semodule -i FIR_policy.pp
```

After that, I rebooted and checked the proper installation:

```
semodule -l | grep FIR_policy
```

Everything is OK. I am able change the type of the file to FIR_t but I can't read and execute the file with user_u although I have defined it in the .te file.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve the problem? Thank you.

Petr